# Querying nested objects in SpringData MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I need to ask a question about a nested object state in my document, which looks like this:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5437248f2dfbc82fcafa9733"),
  "_class" : "conference.Speaker",
  "speakerId" : NumberLong(0),
  "name" : "John Doe",
  "talks" : [{
      "talkId" : NumberLong(0),
      "when" : ISODate("2014-10-17T15:00:00Z"),
      "title" : "Stuff"
    }]
}
```

This document looks fine and it is generated out of 2 classes, `Speaker` and `Talk`, when none of them have any annotations and the former has a List of the laters as a property.

What I need to get is a list of talks with certain name.
Here's what I am tring to do:

```
BasicQuery query = new BasicQuery("{'talks.title' : 'Stuff'}");
```

This fails with `org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: Invalid path reference talks.title! Associations can only be pointed to directly or via their id property!`

I guess it can't use the Id property (since Talk object doesn't have it's own id), and I have no idea what 'can be pointed directly means'.

What's wrong with my query and/or the mapping?

Comment: I guess it's because **talks** is an array. To be pointed directly, it should be `talks.index.title` (index = 0, 1, ...) - of course this style is out of your expectation. Another way is: `Query query = new Query().addCriteria(Criteria.where("talks.title").is("Stuff"));`. Not sure if it's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the error you'll have to give more details: the exact call that is throwing the error, SpringData version, MongoDB version.

The query that you built seems ok, but it won't return `Talk` objects, but instead will return `Speaker` objects that have at least one 'Stuff' talk.

If you want to get only one Talk that has a certain title you can use a *find* with a *projection*:

```
db.talks.find({"talks.title":"Stuff"}, { talks: { $elemMatch: { title: "Stuff" } } })
```

If you'd like all the Talks matching a title you'll have to use an *aggregation*:

```
    db.talks.aggregate(
       // match only speaker with 'Stuff talks'
       { $match : {
          "talks.title": "Stuff"
       }},
       { $unwind : "$talks" },
       { $match : {
          "talks.title": "Stuff"
       }},
       // projection (only talks fields?)
     )
```